# android:animateLayoutChanges won't work in parent layout

Tags: java, android, animation

Suppose I have a layout file structured like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main" android:orientation="vertical" android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    <EditText>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/header1">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/insertionPoint" android:orientation="vertical" android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/header2">
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to dynamically add text fields to the Layout `insertionPoint` and I would like to see an animation of the elements below it (in this case, `header2`) sliding down.

Using `android:animateLayoutChanges` only animates the elements in the layout `insertionPoint`, so there is no animation for `header2`. What should I do?

Just to be more clear: what I would like to do here is something like the animations that we can see in the People app in ICS when we add more fields, like telephone numbers, to a contact.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

API 16 added the `LayoutTransition.CHANGING` animation type, however it is disabled by default.

To enable:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
linearLayout.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

Nice DevBytes video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55wLsaWpQ4g